Can Safari's sidebar hover pop-out hint be disabled?
Sites that have a left-edge menu frequently cause Safari's tab-bar to pop-out, I presume as a discoverable hint that the sidebar can be extracted for tabs, reading list, etc. This animation is annoying and shifts all the left-side content over, occasionally causing errant clicks, and generally just being a nuisance. I know the sidebar is there, I don't want it to do anything unless I explicitly invoke it ala. View -> Show Sidebar or any of the other specific Sidebar views.
I never clicked during this recording:

Can this pop-out animation/hint be disabled?
